# Is it possible to restart an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I just want to restart my iPhone not turn it off + turn it back on.

In Android there is an option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, restarts are possible. Hold the home button and the lock button until the Apple logo is displayed.
Switching it off & on is the same as restarting.

Comment: By the way, restarts actually are possible on the iPhone.

Comment: Can't delete it - it's checked.

Comment: Ok, edited. You deserve the credit though.

Comment: This is a hard reset. NOT RECOMMENDED FOR EVERYDAY USE!

Comment: To repeat what Max Ried said, IT'S NOT RECOMMENDED TO HARD RESET WITHOUT PROPER CAUSE.

Answer (score 4):

You force restart iPhone simply by pressing and holding **both** the home button and the power button until you see the Apple logo. For this force restart both buttons are held simultaneously.

I have been in at least one situation where the phone would not power off and the only way to get the phone back working was to force restart.

This is similar to holding the power button down on a computer and crashing it entirely, and just like a computer, is typically only needed on rare occasions when nothing else will work. Refer to this KB document for more information: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1430.

Comment: Whilst this does restart the device, it's not exactly the same as the proper 'slide to power off' then power on procedure and shouldn't be an effective reboot for a device, only when the standard method fails.

Comment: @grgarside, Thanks, for pointing out: that's a good point. I've gotten used to it, but updated my response with the official KB and a bit more clarification that it a force restart.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an option of restarting an (unjailbroken) iOS device normally with one click (soft reset). However there is a thing called a "hard reset". This is intended for occasions where the iOS device does not react. The hard reset is described in the answers above: Hold *both* Home and Power Button for about ten - twelve seconds (until the apple logo appears). This is not intended for everyday use. To restart an iPhone normally just power it off and power it on again. The difference between the two is that with a soft reset all the memory (RAM) gets written to the disk. When the device boots all of that is loaded into the RAM again. This means that memory leaks will not be resolved this way. On a hard reset all this does not happen and the iPhone does not load what was loaded before. It is equivalent to pulling the plug on a desktop.

On jailbroken devices there are apps available that do a normal restart by clicking a button, but I hardly recommend not to jailbreak your device.

Sources:

[Apple Support Communities](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/2467216?start=0&tstart=0)